# Scrapy Memory Error (too many requests) Python 2.7

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, memory, scrapy

I've been running a crawler in Scrapy to crawl a large site I'd rather not mention.  I use the tutorial spider as a template, then I created a series of starting requests and let it crawl from there, using something like this:

```
def start_requests(self):
        f = open('zipcodes.csv', 'r')
        lines = f.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            zipcode = int(line)
            yield self.make_requests_from_url("http://www.example.com/directory/%05d" % zipcode)
```

To start, there are over 10,000 such pages, then each of those queue up a pretty large directory, from which there are several more pages to queue, etc., and scrapy appears to like to stay "shallow," accumulating requests waiting in memory instead of delving through them and then back up.

The result of this is a repetitive big exception that ends like this:

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py", line 57, in <genexpr>
    work = (callable(elem, *args, **named) for elem in iterable)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py", line 96, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
```

..... (Many more lines) .....

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\selector\lxmldocument.py", line 13, in _factory
    body = response.body_as_unicode().strip().encode('utf8') or '<html/>'
exceptions.MemoryError:
```

Fairly quickly, within an hour or so of a crawler that should take several days, the python executable balloons to 1.8gigs and Scrapy won't function anymore (continuing to cost me *many* wasted dollars in proxy usage fees!).

Is there any way to get Scrapy to dequeue or externalize or iterate over (I don't even know the right words) stored requests to prevent such a memory problem?

(I'm not very proficient in programming, other than to piece together what I see here or in the docs, so I'm not equipped to troubleshoot under the hood, so to speak - I also was unable to install the full python/django/scrapy as 64-bit on W7, after days of trying and reading.)

Comment: Don't set CONCURRENT_ITEMS settings too high. I set it on 60.000 and I got MemoryError too. Did you add any settings on concurrency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can process your urls by batch by only queueing up a few at time every time the spider idles. This avoids having a lot of requests queued up in memory. The example below only reads the next batch of urls from your database/file and queues them as requests only after all the previous requests are done processing.

More info on the `spider_idle` signal: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html#spider-idle

More info on debugging memory leaks: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/leaks.html

```
from scrapy import signals, Spider
from scrapy.xlib.pydispatch import dispatcher


class ExampleSpider(Spider):
    name = "example"
    start_urls = ['http://www.example.com/']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ExampleSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # connect the function to the spider_idle signal
        dispatcher.connect(self.queue_more_requests, signals.spider_idle)

    def queue_more_requests(self, spider):
        # this function will run everytime the spider is done processing
        # all requests/items (i.e. idle)

        # get the next urls from your database/file
        urls = self.get_urls_from_somewhere()

        # if there are no longer urls to be processed, do nothing and the
        # the spider will now finally close
        if not urls:
            return

        # iterate through the urls, create a request, then send them back to
        # the crawler, this will get the spider out of its idle state
        for url in urls:
            req = self.make_requests_from_url(url)
            self.crawler.engine.crawl(req, spider)

    def parse(self, response):
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to reach closure when recursing links over the whole Internet. You will need to limit the recursion in one way or another. Unfortunately the part of the code where you would do this is not shown. The easiest way would be to set a fixed size to the list of pending links to crawl and just don't add any more to the list until it is less than this cap. More advanced solutions would assign priority to pending links based on their surrounding context in the parent page and then do sorted adds to the sorted, fixed-maximum-size priority list of pending links.

Instead of trying to edit or hack the existing code, however, you should see if the built-in settings can accomplish what you want. See this doc page for reference: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html. It looks like the `DEPTH_LIMIT` setting with a value of 1 or more would limit your depth of recursion off the starting pages.

Comment: I think this approach could possibly be detrimental rather than helpful.  The parent response objects is likely larger than all request objects it will generate. Keeping the response open memory in order to limit requests from it would result in more memory usage.